# AWS Glue Job - pass glue catalog table names as parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have a AWS Glue job in pyspark language which loads data from S3/Glue catalog db to snowflake. How can we achieve passing table names as parameters and run the aws glue job in parallel.

can we do it inside glue job or any lambda functions?

Please suggest and share any code/articles.

Thank you in advance.

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 2):

AWS Glue lets you enter your own script, so it's very flexible. You can pass table names as parameters:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html

In this case, Glue job can process these tables sequentially:

- parse the input parameters
- create a loop for each table

  - create_dynamic_frame for reading table
  - transform if necessary
  - write to snowflake
  - process next table

If you want to run separate Glue jobs for each table to process them **in parallel**, then you need to pass only one table to the Glue job, and call the same job for multiple time with a different table name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html

Glue launches an EMR cluster based on the "Number of workers".

I do not know how many tables you will process, and the frequency of calling the Glue job, but it could be better to process the tables sequentialy  with a bigger cluster to utilize resources.

Comment: What will be the best solution to load 100 tables about 500M data in 1.5 hour - 2 hours. will it be ok to create a lambda function and pass through tables and run by batches parallely or loop over glue catalog table name in lambda function or glue job it self ?

Comment: 1) Is 500 M data total? 2) Does each table have multiple files on S3? 3) Do you need spark to transform data?

Comment: 500M is total data , data is on s3 as parquet format and mutilple files. there is no need of any transformations . i am using spark connectors /sql to load data to snwflake